# React native properties

Tags: javascript, properties, react-native

Im really trying to wrap my head around properties and how theyre passed in react.  But I just can't.   No matter what I try, I can't access anything I pass into a component.

I have a main page, that contains a MyProfile component, that Im passing a JSON object into the user property.

```
var myUser = {"name":"test","avatar":"imagelinketc"}

<MyProfile user={myUser} />
```

Then in the MyProfile component, Im setting the user based on the passed property.  But its not working!?

```
class MyProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: props.user,
      loaded:false
    };
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.user.name}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This returns null/undefined.

Then I tried this...

```
class MyProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: null,
      loaded:false
    };
  }

  onComponentWillMount(){
    this.setState({
      user:this.props.user,       
      loaded:true
     });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.user.name}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Still undefined.
I've also tried, just setting a this.user property directly.  Outside of this.state, still undefined.  It seems I can't pass a property into MyProfile.
Whatever I pass ends up being null.  Am I doing this completely backwards??

How do I pass the user from the first page, to the Profile page!!??  Been stuck on this for hours.

PS : I have actually been able to pass properties elsewhere in my App just fine.
And use them inside the components passed to.  Its just this one Component that is giving me grief

Comment: You should not be setting the state manually.

Comment: Elaborate.  I've been doing this all over my app, and its been working so far.  How am I supposed to be setting state?  (not using flux, redux actions etc)  The app is simple, to the point where I load all data at the top, and just pass it to the page that needs it.  Its been working so far until now.  Obviously Im doing it completely wrong though.  Still thinking in terms of regular apps, and not react flow.  PS all the examples seem to set state exactly how I've done here, so Im not sure what you mean when you say dont set it manually

Comment: Can you pass View and Text components?

Comment: ? Im not trying to pass View or Text components.  Im passing the myUser JSON object

Comment: Can you add a rnplay fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do:

1. Change onComponentWillMount to componentWillMount
2. When passing down properties and setting them up in the constructor, you need to reference them as this.props instead of props

Check out the below code to see what I'm talking about:

```
var user = { name: 'Chris', age: 22, location: 'California' }

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      user: user
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <User user={ this.state.user } />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class User extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      user: this.props.user
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <View>
              <Text>{ this.props.user.name }</Text>
              <Text>{ this.props.user.age }</Text>
              <Text>{ this.props.user.location }</Text>
           </View>
  }
}
```